# Update DOM after API Endpoint change in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a NG service that returns objects like this:

```js
    getIndicators(): Observable<Indicator[]> {
        return this.http.get<Indicator[]>('http://localhost:1338/test')
      }
```

In the component @NgOnInit im currently calling for the function service like this:

```js
    const source = timer(1000, 59000);
        //output: 0,1,2,3,4,5......
        const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => {
          this.myService.getIndicators().subscribe(result => (this.indicators = result))
          console.log('timer hit')
        });
```

So it will update the DOM automatically via a rxjs timer, however this is far from optimal. If  I fetch my service getIndicators function on ngOnInit (without timer), i will need to refresh the DOM in order to get the new values that has been updated on the API endpoint, hence the timer.

I know this should be possible to solve with observers of some sort, once the api has updated, the DOM will update. I'm new to RXJS and would love some direction and or examples.

Thanks in advance,
Svante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend unfortunately doesn't have any knowledge of the data in the server without fetching it. So it will have to make recurring calls to keep the data updated. You could however use a `setTimeout()` within the subscription to trigger the call again.

```js
dataStream: any;

ngOnInit() {
  this.triggerStream();
}

triggerStream() {
  if (this.dataStream) {
    this.dataStream.unsubscribe();          // <-- cancel impending requests
  }
  this.dataStream = this.myService.getIndicators().subscribe(
    result => {
      this.indicators = result;
      setTimeout(() => { this.triggerStream() }, 60000);        // <-- fetch again in 60 seconds
    },
    error => {
      // handle error
      setTimeout(() => { this.triggerStream() }, 5000);        // <-- fetch again in 5 seconds
    }
  );
}
```

One advantage of this method is the refetch time could be different for a response and error. For eg. fetch again in 60 seconds if a valid response is received, or else fetch again in 5 seconds.

But you still have to manually trigger the call everytime you need an update from the server. To avoid it, you could look into [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events). They are designed for these situations where a single continuous stream of data is required from the server and it doesn't expect any data from the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `mergeMap`. Inside `ngOnInit` do this:

```
timer(1000, 59000).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.getIndicators())
).subscribe();

getIndicators(){
   // your api call
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to remove the timer, since it could ask for an update where there is no update, how can I observe the api endpoint and update DOM accordingly when there is changes without using a timer? Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no way of finding about the changes without calling the api..
you can return a flag from your api. if its true then update your data else don't do anything.